# Image in document directory is not changing after overwriting

Tags: ios, swift, local-storage, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I need to upload image in local and to get it later. Now my problem is I can store and get the correct image while I am trying at very first time after launching the app. But when I try to upload the same file with same name but with different image, I am getting the previously stored image.

Here's my code:

```
    let i = "image1"

    let str = String(i).appending(".png")

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(str)

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths) {
        do {
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: paths)
            print("old image has been removed")
        } catch {
            print("an error during a removing")
        }
    }

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadingImage!, 0.5)

    fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
```

and I am getting the URL as String like,

```
let myImagePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths)
```

Someone please help me to find the problem in my code...

Comment: you need to delete the previous one and update image in same name

Comment: Yes, I did remove the previous image as I mentioned in the code.

Comment: its your log print `image has been removed` or not

Comment: I used this "try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: paths)" and its removing. Evethough I got the previous one.

Comment: is this possible to attach your project

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik do you have any idea?

Comment: your code is fine and correct, are you verified your image has deleted or not  (either manually or progrmatically)

Comment: Try to compare the data on each steps. If had deleted old file (you said that it was checked), created new file with new data( data had to be checked), and read image from new file( data had to be checked) then you should have new data.

Comment: Yes, it's getting deleted. I'll check each steps.

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
imageData?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: paths))
```

instead of

```
fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
```

Comment: Hi, writing file with different filename is working for me, but while updating the image with the same name is not working. I have used your code, can you tell me how to remove the written file, I have used my code I attached above, but I think it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why your code should not work. However, the required workflow to safely replace a file is:

```
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
    } catch let error {
        print("Cannot delete file on device: \(path): \(error)")
        return
    }
}
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
```